# How to clone unmanaged package

Tags: unmanaged-package

I have an unmanaged package that has a dependecy on a third party managed package. I want to use this unmanaged package to create a new org to do some work. However, the new instance doesn't have this 3rd party package installed on it and due to licensing/pricing it probably isn't going to.

If I could clone the unmanaged package and remove the dependecny on the 3rd party package, I should be fine. However I can't seem to figure out a way to do that. The unamanaged package has a lot in it so recreating it with everything except this 3rd party tool would be hard.

Is there any way to do this in a more automated fashion?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can remove that dependency automatically. Other than that you can try going like this:

1. Using [Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_install.htm) / [SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) / some IDE ([MavensMate](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate), [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/)) download all metadata related to the package.
2. Try deploying it to another system. You will need [SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) or [Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_install.htm) for this depending on the org setup. Get errors, specifically showing places where the dependency exists
3. Resolve dependency issues
4. Upload again, successfully this time

I think this should work for you. Will gladly provide any further assistance